# don't allow non member show jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i design a jsp page but i want only some one that login as member of my site(have session with some futures) see that page and if some one that is not member try to see page refer to a custom eror page.can you advise me something helpfull?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> User Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@include file="Header.jsp" %>
${welcome } ${name} ${family }
</body>
</html>
```

any help fall me in greatfull...

Comment: honestly honestly honestly why -1??i am a begginer and my fault is this?

Comment: perhaps the downvoter saw the question as not well formulated. While this might be said, it is clear enough what you are trying to achieve, hence my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

1. Implement `javax.servlet.Filter`. Call `chain.doFilter(..)` only if you find a user in the session; otherwise call response.sendRedirect("notLoggedIn.jsp");
2. Map it in web.xml (`<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>`) (or if you are using servlet 3.0 - use [`@WebFilter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) on the filter class). Map the filter to the path(s) you want to protect.